# query stackoverflow questions by language and date?

Tags: data.stackexchange.com

I see that we have a tool called "stack exchange data query" but I don't see there examples of using the tool and I don't see in the fields "programming language" or something similar?

Comment: Do you reffer to: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: yes meolic i refer to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the guide i was after: [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#introduction)

basically this tool give you the abillity to query stackexchange db.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with us. You can mark your own answer as accepted if it solves your problem.